# I want to write a Reordering User Interface? How to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul style="padding: 5px; margin-left: 20px;">
Hardware
<li style="padding: 10px; margin-left: 40px;">Product 1</li>
<li style="padding: 10px; margin-left: 40px;">Product 2</li>
<li style="padding: 10px; margin-left: 40px;">Product 3</li>
<li style="padding: 10px; margin-left: 40px;">Product 4</li>
<li style="padding: 10px; margin-left: 40px;">Product 5</li>
</ul>
```

I have this structure i want to do a reodering interface where user can move product 5 up in the hiearchy by click up arrow and likewise bring something down. I want to do this using javascript of jQuery. I just need some hint about how to do it right.

Comment: Have a look at [jquery ui sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

Comment: I would start with semantic markup.

Comment: @bazmegakapa i think i have the correct markup. Please suggest something

Comment: @sushil Your previous markup was not semantic, and this one won't validate. Concerning jQuery, you can simply use `before()` and `after()` for this task. You could store the product IDs on the elements in `data-` attributes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/ECpfK/

This code should help you get started:

```
var $moveProduct = $("li").eq(4); // product5

$("#up").click(function() {
    $moveProduct.prev().before($moveProduct);
});

$("#down").click(function() {
    $moveProduct.next().after($moveProduct);
});
```

It moves the product5 up and down.

I simplified your markup, by moving the inline css to a separated stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you may want to consider jQuery-UI.

It's very simple to build your own, but the existing ones out there are really polished: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two things to solve. You have to make those DOM elements move and you have to find a way to collect the current order in an input element (to be able to send it to the server).

Moving the element is quite easy using jQuery's magic functions. @Jose gave you a simple but working example.

I suggest you save the IDs of the products in `data-` attributes, because then it will be easier to work with those. You will need a method that collects the IDs in the currently set up order and saves them in a comma-separated string (whenever the order changes, you have to call this). That you can send to the server.

So with a markup like this:

```
<ol class="orderable-list">
    <li data-id="24">Terrific Product</li>
    <li data-id="32">Amazing Product</li>
    <li data-id="11">Must-buy Product</li>
<ol>
<input type="hidden" id="current-order" />
```

You can easily gather the current order using `.map()` and save it to the input:

```
var order = $('.orderable-list li').map(function () {
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get();

$('#current-order').val(order.join(','));
```

Please check [this jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9Twv/).

Comment: I have also to support ie-7. How would i go about with the data attribute in ie7. Moreover my html is not html5

Comment: @sushilbharwani IE7 will have no problem with it. The only question is valid HTML. If the `data-` attributes are the **only** ones that would make your document not valid, you can either switch to HTML5 doctype, which would be understood fine by all browsers, or use some other standard attribute (like `id="product-24"`, it is easy to get the ID 24 from this).